# How to send email via SSL and Indy in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, email, ssl, smtp, indy

I want to send email to Yahoo mail using Indy. But Yahoo uses 465 port with SSL connection. I don't know how to implement that in my program. I have read about TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component on internet, but couldn't find such component in Delphi 7. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) library is much easier to use. Look at the code example I use: [How To Use SMTP with TLS](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:smtpsend)

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 6/7 the component was called `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket`. This was Indy 8/9. It still uses Open SSL. I don't know why they changed the name in Indy 10.

Comment: Because the SSL IOHandler architecture changed in Indy 10 to allow custom descendants, so the name of the native component had to change accordingly as well.